# std::declval<T>(), SFINAE and deleted constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, sfinae

Playing with SFINAE for method detection in C++11, I wrote this little running example:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo
{
  Foo();// = delete;
  Foo(int);

  void my_method();
};

template <typename T, typename ENABLE = void>
struct Detect_My_Method 
   : std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T>
struct Detect_My_Method<T, decltype(T().my_method())> 
   : std::true_type
{
};

int main()
{
  static_assert(!Detect_My_Method<double>::value, "");
  static_assert(Detect_My_Method<Foo>::value, "");
}
```

that worked as expected.

However if I delete the empty constructor of Foo:

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo() = delete;
  Foo(int);

  void my_method();
};
```

the example is **not working** anymore and I get this error message:

```
g++ -std=c++11 declVal.cpp 
declVal.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
declVal.cpp:33:3: error: static assertion failed
   static_assert(Detect_My_Method<Foo>::value, "");
```

**Question:** explanation and how to solve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the empty constructor is **deleted** the construction:

```
decltype(Foo().my_method());
```

is **not valid** anymore and the compiler complains immediately

```
error: use of deleted function ‘Foo::Foo()’
```

One solution is to use [`std::decval<T>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

> Converts any type T to a reference type, making it possible to use
>   member functions in decltype expressions **without the need to go
>   through constructors**.

Hence replacing:

```
template <typename T>
struct Detect_My_Method<T, decltype(T().my_method())> 
   : std::true_type
{
};
```

by

```
template <typename T>
struct Detect_My_Method<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().my_method())> 
   : std::true_type
{
};
```

solves the problem.

**Learned lesson:**

```
decltype(Foo().my_method());                // invalid
decltype(std::declval<Foo>().my_method());  // fine
```

are not equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

In addition, there is another way to define the test that requires neither a reference or a pointer to the object nor a specific signature of the function:

```
template<class T>
typename std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::my_method)>::type test_member_function_my_method(int);

template<class T>
std::false_type test_member_function_my_method(...);

template<class T>
using has_member_function_my_method = decltype(test_member_function_my_method<T>(0));
```

Usage:

```
static_assert(!has_member_function_my_method<double>::value, "");
static_assert(has_member_function_my_method<Foo>::value, "");
```

Comment: This isn't *exactly* equivalent, as the `declval` method can detect function objects. If `T` has a member variable `my_method` with an `operator()`, it will detect that as valid. That may or may not be desirable, or you may or may not care.

Comment: @Justin You are right. It also doesn't handle overloaded functions because the call arguments are not involved here.